# Android minSdkVersion opposing dependancies

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk, android-api-levels

I am performing Android development for a specific remote research trial (not to be distributed, single use case).

The required dependencies (DJI and Parrot hardware SDKs) are only compatible with specific API's. One has a min API of 19, the other has a min API of 24. The dependencies are used one at a time and not simultaniously.

I have tried `tools:overrideLibrary="xyz..."` in AndroidManifest, this allowed the build to compile but the app hangs when the DJI SDK registers.

Is there a way to set minSdk for different dependancies?
Specifically the first time a particular section of the application is run (the section that validates the hardware SDK)?

Thanks for your help.